# Set button text inside action

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button in which i want to set the text programatically.

as for right now i have the following:

```
@IBAction func saveButtonClicked(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    sender.setTitle("Action", for: UIControlState.normal)
    closeKeyboard()
}
```

the issue is, that this is an action outlet, so the text only appends to the button when i press it..

I tried to put the setTitle inside the viewdidload function, but it wont compile. 
How do i make the text constant? do i have to make multiple outlets, or can it be done in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create an Outlet named button_1.

```
@IBOutlet var button_1: UIButton!
```

---

Add this in viewDidLoad

```
button_1.setTitle("Button text", forState: .Normal)
```

To fire an action when button is clicked use this:

```
 @IBAction func ButtonClicked(sender: UIButton){
        button_1.setTitle("You clicked me", forState: .Normal)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either draw IBOutlets to the button in order to set its title.

```
btnOutlet.setTitle("yourTitle", forState: .Normal)
```

Also, you can set tag to your button from storyboard, access it in the viewDidLoad() and then set its title as follows :-

```
 let btn:UIButton = self.view.viewWithTag(500) as! UIButton
 btn.setTitle("yourTitle", forState: .Normal)
```